# Profiling an ember js application

Tags: ember.js

Has anybody any experience with this?

Know of any tools etc?

It seems that simple timestamps do not work, as they all come out with the same value due to being run in the same run loop.

I am trying to find some bottlenecks in my app.

Comment: I think I should be using Instrumentation, as below, but I am not quite sure how to instrument arbitrary code...

http://tobyho.com/2013/03/12/perf-testing-ember.js-views/

Answer (score 2):

**ember-renderspeed** gives you insights on Views rendering speed right out of the box, just include the script.

https://github.com/eviltrout/ember-renderspeed

Comment: Cheers, but I would also like to time the actions in my app, not only the view/template rendering